# Parsing optional and not optional arguments

Tags: bash, parsing

I am new with bash and after reading and trying a lot about how to parse arguments I cannot what I really want to do I want to parse optional and not optional arguments. More specifically I want to parse 3 arguments, first (a fastaq file) second (a second optional fastaq file) a third argument that will be a directory.

`my_script.sh  -f1 file1.fasta --f2 file2.fasta  -d/home/folder1/folder2`
or

`my_script.sh -f1 file1.fasta -d /home/folder1/folder2`

I have tried to do this in many ways but I dont know how to let the program identifies when there are two fasta files and a directory and, when there is only one fasta file and a directory.

With this arguments I want to save them in variables because they will  be used later by third parties.

I have tried this:

```
for i in "$@"; do
 case $i in
   -f1=|-fasta1=)
     FASTA1="${i#=}"
     shift # past argument=value
     ;;
   -d) DIRECTORY=$2
  shift 2
     ;;
   -d=|-directory=) DIRECTORY="${i#=}"
   shift # past argument=value
     ;;
   --f2=|-fasta2=) FASTA2="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
     ;;
   *)
     ;;
 esac
done
```

But I just got this

```
scripts_my_first_NGS]$ ./run.sh -f1 fasta.fasta -d /home/folder1
FASTA1  =
DIRECTORY     =
FASTA2     =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to add a separate parser for versions of the options where they aren't used with the equal sign.

Also your `shift` commands are useless since you're processing a `for` loop.  So convert it to to a `while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do` loop instead.

I also added a few modifications which I suggest be added.

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
    -f1|-fasta1)
        FASTA1=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -f1=*|-fasta1=*)
        FASTA1=${1#*=}
        ;;
    -d|-directory)
        DIRECTORY=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -d=*|-directory=*)
        DIRECTORY=${1#*=}
        ;;
    -f2|fasta2)
        FASTA2=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -f2=*|-fasta2=*)
        FASTA2=${1#*=}
        ;;
    -*)
        echo "Invalid option: $1" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    --)
        # Do FILES+=("${@:2}") maybe
        break
        ;;
    *)
        # TODO
        # Do FILES+=("$1") maybe
        ;;
    esac

    shift
done
```

The "parser" for the with-equal and non-with-equal versions of the options can also be unified by
using a helper function:

```
function get_opt_arg {
    if [[ $1 == *=* ]]; then
        __=${1#*=}
        return 1
    elif [[ ${2+.} ]]; then
        __=$2
        return 0 # Tells that shift is needed
    else
        echo "No argument provided to option '$1'." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
}

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
    -d|-directory|-d=*|-directory=*)
        get_opt_arg "$@" && shift
        DIRECTORY=$__
        ;;
    -f1|-fasta1|-f1=*|-fasta1=*)
        get_opt_arg "$@" && shift
        FASTA1=$__
        ;;
    -f2|fasta2|-f2=*|-fasta2=*)
        get_opt_arg "$@" && shift
        FASTA2=$__
        ;;
    -*)
        echo "Invalid option: $1" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    --)
        # Do FILES+=("${@:2}") maybe
        break
        ;;
    *)
        # TODO
        # Do FILES+=("$1") maybe
        ;;
    esac

    shift
done
```

### Update

I found a complete solution to command-line parsing without relying on getopt[s] and it does it even more consistentlty: https://konsolebox.io/blog/2022/05/14/general-command-line-parsing-solution-without-using-getopt-s.html

Comment: This worked Thanks. I have a few questions. Why directory is "twice". Why some have = and other =*. And at the end what do you want to means with the last comments TODO Do FILES+=("$1") maybe

Comment: Those last parts are for default arguments that aren't options. Most of the time you use it with file arguments.

"Why twice?" Because `-d /home/folder1/folder2` and `-d=/home/folder1/folder2` are different forms. The former allocates two positional parameter spaces and the latter allocates only one and includes the option  argument to the option.

Answer (score 1):

Never parse command line options on your own!

Instead either use the Bash function [`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-getopts), if you do not need GNU style long options or use use the GNU program [`getopt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html) otherwise.

The following examples uses an array for `FASTA`. `FASTA1` is `${FASTA[0]}` and `FASTA2` is `${FASTA[1]}`. In case of `getopts` this makes it possible to use just one option character (`-f`) multiple times.

Using `getopts` with only one-character options:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

FASTA=()
DIRECTORY=

while getopts 'f:d:' option; do
  case "$option" in
    f)
      FASTA+=("$OPTARG")
      ;;
    d)
      DIRECTORY="$OPTARG"
      ;;
    *)
      printf 'ERROR: Invalid argument\n' >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [[ -z ${FASTA[0]} ]]; then
  printf 'ERROR: FASTA1 missing\n' >&2
  exit 1
fi

if [[ -z $DIRECTORY ]]; then
  printf 'ERROR: DIRECTORY missing\n' >&2
  exit 1
fi

printf 'FASTA1 = %s\n' "${FASTA[0]}"
printf 'FASTA2 = %s\n' "${FASTA[1]}"
printf 'DIRECTORY = %s\n' "$DIRECTORY"
```

Usage:

```
run -f file1.fasta -f file2.fasta -d /home/folder1/folder2
```

Using `getopt` with one-character and GNU style long options mixed:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

FASTA=()
DIRECTORY=

options=$(getopt -o d: -l f1: -l f2: -- "$@") || {
  printf 'ERROR: Invalid argument\n' >&2
  exit 1
}
eval set -- "$options"

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    --f1)
      FASTA[0]="$2"
      shift 2;;
    --f2)
      FASTA[1]="$2"
      shift 2;;
    -d)
      DIRECTORY="$2"
      shift 2;;
    --)
      shift
      break;;
    *)
      break;;
  esac
done

if [[ -z ${FASTA[0]} ]]; then
  printf 'ERROR: FASTA1 missing\n' >&2
  exit 1
fi

if [[ -z $DIRECTORY ]]; then
  printf 'ERROR: DIRECTORY missing\n' >&2
  exit 1
fi

printf 'FASTA1 = %s\n' "${FASTA[0]}"
printf 'FASTA2 = %s\n' "${FASTA[1]}"
printf 'DIRECTORY = %s\n' "$DIRECTORY"
```

Usage:

```
run --f1 file1.fasta --f2 file2.fasta -d /home/folder1/folder2
```

Comment: `getopt[s]` adds unnecessary complexity just for the sake of being able to specify two or more short options in a single argument.  Also getopt[s] has limitations.  It's has something to do with long options, and maybe with optional arguments as well.

Comment: @konsolebox It is neither more complex nor unnecessary. Your second and third sentence just shows that did not read my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure where to look. Can you just mention your main point? This example does not invalidate the difficulty of implementing option parsing with getopt or getopts. There are many variations which cannot be made applicable to them. I wish I could recall those limitations.

Comment: noteworthy, in the script above with getopt, 'eval set -- ...' is needed to update (rewrite) the argument array ("$@") with the output of getopt , [url](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383864/207995). I would add 'unset options' after eval to emphasize that the 'options' variable is no longer needed.